# Calling object in python with extra parentheisis

Tags: python

Can any one tell me what is the use of extra parentheisis on the side when calling an object in python as shown in the example below:

```
initial = ContractfMapp (context={"context_data": self.context})(pref_data)
```

I don't understand what is the use of the additional parameter on the side, does this mean we are passing data to this ContractMapp object.

Comment: It means `ContractfMapp()` itself returns some callable object, which you are then calling with `pref_data` as an argument.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are passing parameters to the `ContractfMapp` object. Specifically, a `ContractfMapp` object is callable. You can verify this:

```
callable(ContractfMapp(context={"context_data": self.context}))
>>> True
```

It may make more sense to see that line written like this:

```
f = ContractfMapp(context={"context_data": self.context})
initial = f(pref_data)
```